# MassTransit with RabbitMQ - publishing exception after another bus restart

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

According to release note for MassTransit 7.1.0 version the bus restart should be possible - https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.0.html#re-start-the-bus-finally.
Unfortunately for MassTransit configured to use RebbitMQ I'm getting exception on message publish after another bus restart. It works fine to and after first restart but after the second restart publish operation throws `MassTransit.TransportUnavailableException: The RabbitMQ send transport is stopped`.

Below code of simple application (using MassTransit 7.1.3) exposing the problem:

```cs
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MassTransitRestartIssue
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddLogging(logConfig =>
            {
                logConfig.AddConsole();
            });

            services.AddMassTransit(config =>
            {
                config.AddConsumer<TestConsumer>();

                config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("localhost", "test", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
                });
            });

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var busControl = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();
            var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

            await busControl.StartAsync();

            try
            {
                await busControl.Publish(new TestEvent("test message 1"));

                // restart bus
                await busControl.StopAsync();
                await busControl.StartAsync();

                await busControl.Publish(new TestEvent("test message 2"));

                // another restart bus
                await busControl.StopAsync();
                await busControl.StartAsync();

                await busControl.Publish(new TestEvent("test message 3"));
                // throws - MassTransit.TransportUnavailableException: The RabbitMQ send transport is stopped: MassTransitRestartIssue:TestEvent

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "error");
            }
            finally
            {
                await busControl.StopAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public record TestEvent(string Message)
    {
    }

    public class TestConsumer :
        IConsumer<TestEvent>
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TestConsumer(ILogger<TestConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestEvent> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Test event consummed - {context.Message.Message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a bug or intended behavior? If it intended how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Issue [created](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2245) and fixed. Good catch.